# ifelse resulting in NA for levels with special characters

Tags: r, if-statement

**DATA**

Please follow [**this link**](https://drive.google.com/drive/folders/0B5B6N7WsEfbdanlFc0JfVUp0RXM?usp=sharing) to find the .dbf file.

I imported it into R as below

```
library(foreign)
LRI_rocks <- read.dbf("LRI_rocks.dbf")
```

As you can see, below, in the levels of column `Top_Rock` 
There are some levels that have **â€”** inside them.

```
> levels(LRI_rocks$Top_Rock)
 [1] "Ashes older than Taupo pumice"                                                   
 [2] "Gravels"                                                                         
 [3] "Greywacke"                                                                       
 [4] "Kaharoa & Taupo ashes"                                                           
 [5] "Loess"                                                                           
 [6] "Mudstone or fine siltstone â€”  jointed"                                         
 [7] "Mudstone or fine siltstone â€” massive"                                          
 [8] "Ngauruhoe ash"                                                                   
 [9] "Peat"                                                                            
[10] "River"                                                                           
[11] "Sands â€” windblown"                                                             
[12] "Sandstone or coarse siltstone â€” massive"                                       
[13] "Taupo & Kaharoa breccia & volcanic alluvium"                                     
[14] "town/urbanarea/oxidationpond"                                                    
[15] "Unconsolidated to moderately consolidated clays, silts, sands, tephra & breccias"
[16] "Undifferentiated floodplain alluvium"
```

I want to convert the levels of `Top_Rock` to numbers as below

```
library(dplyr)
df <-  LRI_rocks %>% 
  dplyr::select(Top_Rock) %>% 
  dplyr::mutate(top_rock_no = ifelse(Top_Rock =="Ashes older than Taupo pumice", 1, 
                                     ifelse(Top_Rock == "Gravels", 1, 
                                            ifelse(Top_Rock == "Greywacke", 1, 
                                                   ifelse(Top_Rock == "Kaharoa & Taupo ashes", 1, 
                                                          ifelse(Top_Rock == "Loess", 1, 
                                                                 ifelse(Top_Rock == "Mudstone or fine siltstone â€”  jointed", 3,
                                                                        ifelse(Top_Rock == "Mudstone or fine siltstone â€” massive", 3,
                                                                               ifelse(Top_Rock == "Ngauruhoe ash", 1,
                                                                                      ifelse(Top_Rock == "Peat", 3,
                                                                                             ifelse(Top_Rock == "Sands â€” windblown", 1,
                                                                                                    ifelse(Top_Rock == "Sandstone or coarse siltstone â€” massive", 2,
                                                                                                           ifelse(Top_Rock == "Taupo & Kaharoa breccia & volcanic alluvium", 2,
                                                                                                                  ifelse(Top_Rock == "Unconsolidated to moderately consolidated clays, silts, sands, tephra & breccias", 3,
                                                                                                                         ifelse(Top_Rock == "Undifferentiated floodplain alluvium", 2, NA)
                                                                                                                  ))))))))))))))
```

All levels with **â€”** have been replaced with NA.

**QUESTION**

Any suggestion how to convert levels with **â€”** to the numbers I have assigned in `ifelse` instead of having them as `NA`?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use `plyr`'s mapvalues function without having to refer to the strings explicitly:

`... %>% mutate(top_rock_no = plyr::mapvalues(Top_Rock, from=levels(Top_Rock), to=c(1,1,1,1,1,3,3,1,3,1,2,2,3,2)))`

Answer (score 2):

A base R option would be to create a named `vector` and use it to match the key/value and replace the original vector

```
LRI_rocks$(top_rock_no <-  with(LRI_rocks, setNames(c(1,1,1,1,1,3,3,1,3,NA, 1,2,2, NA, 3,2), 
                                levels(Top_Rock))[Top_Rock])
```

#### data

```
v1 <- c("Ashes older than Taupo pumice", "Gravels", "Greywacke", "Kaharoa & Taupo ashes", 
"Loess", "Mudstone or fine siltstone â€”  jointed", 
"Mudstone or fine siltstone â€” massive", 
"Ngauruhoe ash", "Peat", "River", "Sands â€” windblown", 
"Sandstone or coarse siltstone â€” massive", 
"Taupo & Kaharoa breccia & volcanic alluvium", "town/urbanarea/oxidationpond", 
"Unconsolidated to moderately consolidated clays, silts, sands, tephra & breccias", 
"Undifferentiated floodplain alluvium")

set.seed(43)
LRI_rocks <- data.frame(Top_Rock = factor(sample(v1, 50, replace=TRUE), levels = v1))
```